# Using LINQ to JOIN two datatables using two key columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join, datatable

Datatable A:

Key1  | Key2   | A    | B

[   1       1      ...      ]

[   1       2      ...      ]

Datatable B:

Key1  | Key2   | x   | Y

[   1       1      ...      ]

[   1       2      ...      ]

Desired result:

Key1  | Key2   | A    | B |  X | Y

[   1       1      ...                ]

[   1       2      ...                ]

In the end result columns A, B, X and Y have been added to the new datatable. This happened because key1 and key2 were equal in both datatable A and B. Would this be possible to do with a full outer join, given a condition - (Key1 and Key2 are euqal) ?

Comment: Can you put the data in your Data tables in a more readable way? Sorry i am still not quite following

Comment: Maybe a T-SQL example of how you might do this in the database itself will help understand the problem and illuminate the answer.

Comment: @Shyju I'm on it, haven't found a way to properly format yet.

Comment: if we could see the data in an actual data table format.  one table for A, B and the result.

Comment: Are you assuming B[....] and Y[...] contain the same values?

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. There are *NO* tables. It deals with entities. Instead of joins you should have *relations* between *entities*. This would allow you to load all data simply by querying for the root objects

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=linq+full+outer+join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list1 = (from t1 in dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                    Key1 = t1.Field<int>("Key1"),
                    Key2 = t1.Field<int>("Key2"),
                    A = t1.Field<string>("A"),
                    B = t1.Field<string>("B")
                });

var list2 = (from b in dataTable2.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                    Key1 = b.Field<int>("Key1"),
                    Key2 = b.Field<int>("Key2"),
                    X = b.Field<string>("X"),
                    Y = b.Field<string>("Y")
                });

// Now join the 2 collections and get the result you want.

var result = (from x in list1
                join y in list2 on new { x.Key1,x.Key2} equals new { y.Key1,y.Key2 }
                select new { A = x.A, X = y.X }).ToList();
```

Assuming Key1 and Key2 are `int` type and A.B,X and Y are of `string` type.

Comment: Won't `AsEnumerable` load everything from the database?

Comment: From msdn **The AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>) method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<T> itself.**

Comment: How can I automate this process? Say I only know the 2 datatables have the key1 and key2 columns, but I don't know what other columns they have (I can safely assume they are different columns in the 2 datatables though). I'm asking because here it was done manually (for column X,Y, A and B).

Comment: @Shyju Also, what if datatable does exist in memory but is empty? Can what I ask be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code friend :

```
var req = (from A in DatatableA
       join B in DatatableB 
        on A.Key1
            equals B.Key1  into DatatableResult
            select new
           {
                  Key1 = A.Key1    ,
                 Key2 = A.Key2    ,
               A= A.A ,
               x= B.x ,
               y= B.y ,

             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I do this with an empty table? Say table A was empty, and B was the same as in my question. How would I get the same result table as in the question above?